# Одномерные-двумерные массивы в языке C

Tags: c, массивы

Есть лабораторная по программированию на C.
Вопрос по 3 заданиям. Я покажу задание и то, что у меня есть, то, как я вижу, НО оно работает неправильно. Я очень прошу вас помочь мне разобраться, если не сложно - написать код.

**1 задача**: Заполнить массив array[N] случайными целыми числами из диапазона [A; B], сумма цифр которых не превышает MAX. Вывести массив на экран в строку. 
**Мои мысли**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 45
#define A 5
#define B 6510
#define MAX 10
int main(void) {
    int i, n, s, array[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        s = 0;
        n = (A + rand() % (B - A + 1));
        printf("%d  ", n);
        while (n > 0) {
            s += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        printf("%d\n", s);
        if (s < MAX) {

            array[i] = n;
            printf("array[%d] = %d ", i, array[i]);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Задача 2**: Заполнить одномерный массив из 25 элементов случайными целыми числами от -99 до +99 и вывести его в файл. Найти и дописать в файл среднее значение элементов в первой половине массива и среднее значение элементов во второй половине массива. 
**Мои мысли**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 11

int main() {

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "w");
    int srednee, sum, i, A = -99, B = 99;
    int array[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = A + rand() % (B - A + 1);
        fprintf(file, "%d\n", array[i]);

    }
    fprintf(file, "\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
        srednee = sum / N;
    }

    fprintf(file, "%d\n", sum);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Самое грустное здесь - не работает даже простое нахождение среднего значения во всем массиве.

**Пожалуйста, не нужно писать заоблачные программы, это нужно сделать максимально просто для понимания, можно даже костыльно. **
Всем, кто откликнется, сразу говорю большое спасибо, вы мне очень поможете!

Answer (score 2):

**задание 1:**

**ошибка 1** в том, что вы или заполняете элемент массива или не заполняете элемент массива, т.е. по сути делаете 1 попытку,

а попыток сгенерировать случайное число с нужными свойствами должно быть столько, сколько нужно

**ошибка 2** в том, что вычисляя цифры вы уменьшаете `n` до нуля, а потом эту же `n` записываете в ячейку массива - т.е. вы всегда в массив записываете 0!

поэтому переменную надо дублировать

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    s = 0;
    n = (A + rand() % (B - A + 1));
    printf("%d  ", n);
    while (n > 0) {
        s += n % 10;
        n /= 10; // ОШИБКА - уменьшаем n, хотя потом будем им пользоваться
    }
    printf("%d\n", s);

    // ОШИБКА - вот тут одна попытка всего
    if (s < MAX) {

        array[i] = n;
        printf("array[%d] = %d ", i, array[i]);
    }
}
```

надо так:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    s = 0;
    value = 0;

    do {
        n = (A + rand() % (B - A + 1));
        value = n
        while (n > 0) {
            s += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
    } while (s >= MAX);

    array[i] = value;
}
```

**ВАЖНО**

поскольку поиск подходящего числа может занять значительное время ~ диапазону чисел среди которых это число будет искаться, то можно сделать следующее:

```
// ищем все подходящие числа
int values[B];
int values_size = 0;

for (i = A; i <=B; i++) {
    s = 0;
    n = i;
    while (n > 0) {
        s += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    if (s < MAX) {
        values[values_size] = i;
        values_size ++;
    }
}

// ищем случайные числа из ранее найденных подходящих

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    n = rand() % values_size;
    array[i] = values[n[;
}
```

**задание 2:**

вас же просили среднее подсчитать первой половины и второй половины массива, а вы среднее целого массива считаете

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
    srednee = sum / N;
}
```

кроме того вы его считаете неправильно - вы вычисляете среднее как целое, а надо как число с плавающей точкой - вмеcто `int` надо `float`,

кроме того вы еще и делите на N накапливаемую сумму сразу для каждого нового элемента, а не в конце - в итоге у вас не среднее получается, а мусор, т.е. вместо
ave = (a1 + a2 + a3) / N
вы получаете
trash = ((a1 / N + a2) / N + a3) / N = a1 / N^3 + a2 / N^2 + a3 / N

надо

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sum += array[i];        
}
srednee = (float)sum / N; // если не конвертировать, то будет деление целого на целое
```

Ну и раз вам надо вычислить для двух половинок массива, то и будет:

```
for (i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {...}
sum1 = sum1 / (N / 2)

for (i = N / 2; i < N; i++) {...}
sum2 = sum2 / (N - N / 2)
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете крутить цикл, пока `rand` не вернет нужное значение? Это может быть достаточно долго. Может лучше пройтись по всем числам в нужном диапазоне и заносить подходящие в массив, а потом уже рандомно выбирать числа из массива?

Comment: Если писать так, как вы предложили ошибку 2 исправить, то программа не работает. Консоль вообще принимает значения с клавиатуры, не реагирую ни на энтер, ни на что другое, в общем - не выполняется код.

В принципе, да, логично занести все, а потом выбрать. Но я не представляю, как это сделать...

Comment: @EOF, не очень и долго будет крутиться, даже если надо требовать сумму в 2 (от 5 до 6510 это всего лишь число 11), то программа для каждого числа прокрутится несколько тысяч раз. Я согласен, что по времени это не эффективно и сначала лучше создать массив и заполнить его только подходящими числами, а потом выбирать случайно из этого массива. Но в первой итерации и на коленке такой вариант подойдет.

Comment: @Дмитрий Благодер, значит долго ищется, хотя мне казалось, что должно побыстрее - тогда смотрите вариант предложенный тут EOF и который я чуть-чуть подробнее расписал в комментарии

Comment: добавил в свой ответ код для быстрого поиска подходящих чисел

Comment: Можно прокомментировать, что происходит в 1 задаче по вашему коду, там, где подписано "ВАЖНО"? Я правильно понимаю, что там массивы получились еще? Какова роль values[B], я не увидел его применение. Как из values[B] получился values[n]?

Comment: Как я написал выше - проблема в том, что случайно искать подходящее число в заданном диапазоне [A, B] долго - ведь кол-во попыток в самом худшем случае может быть бесконечно много (а в самом лучшем мы сразу находим нужное число с 1 попытки). Поэтому надежнее сделать так: сначала найти все числа в диапазоне [A, B] у которых сумма цифр меньше `MAX` и записать их в отдельный массив, а уже потом выбирать случайно число из этого массива. Поскольку там только нужные нам числа (по сумме цифр), то не надо делать множество попыток найти нужное число - любое число из массива нас устраивает.

Comment: ну а сам алгоритм - создаем массив размером `B - A + 1`, т.е. по максимальному кол-ву чисел в диапазоне `[A, B]` (я из лени взял размер `B`, поскольку он еще больше), в него влезут все наши найденные числа и дальше в цикле начинам перебирать все числа от `A` до `B` и записывать подходящие в массив, как только записали число в массив увеличиваем значение границы массива на 1. В конечном итоге по этой границе мы знаем сколько чисел было записано в массив и значит ищем случайное число в этом диапазоне индексов `[0, size)`

Comment: По 1 задаче вопросов нет, спасибо. По 2 задаче вопросы такие: структура программы такова, что 1) ввели массив, 2) средние значения в 1 и 2 половинах, 3) дописывание в массив этих значений. 
Цикл `for (i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {...}
sum1 = sum1 / (N / 2)` перебирает 1 половину массива. У него в теле я должен сохранять какие-то переменные?

Что за код: `sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sum += array[i];        
}
srednee = (float)sum / N;`? Я понимаю, что это сумма, но где мне его использовать?

Comment: вы же массив должны были в файл по условию задачи записать? ну так и 2 числа запишите в файл (правда я из условия не понял - целое оно должно быть или действительное)

Comment: Да, нужно дописать значения в массив, но это не проблема. Что-то нужно сохранять в циклах? Просто я собрал программу, но не понимаю ,что там и как это что-то работает.

Comment: не понял - в цикле вы записываете массив в файл поэлементно, а затем в двух циклах вычисляете суммы что средних значений и отдельно записываете средние значения в файл

Comment: `FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "w");
 int srednee, srednee2, sum1, sum2, sum, i, A = -99, B = 99;
 int array[N];
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  array[i] = A + rand() % (B - A + 1);
  fprintf(file, "%d\n", array[i]);
 }
 fprintf(file, "***");
 sum = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  sum += array[i];
 }
 srednee = (float) sum / N;

 for (i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
  sum1 = sum1 / (N / 2);
 }

 for (i = N / 2; i < N; i++) {
  sum2 = sum2 / (N - N / 2);
 }

 fprintf(file, "%d\n", srednee);`

Comment: Вот сам код, но я запутался в переменных теперь...

Answer (score 0):

Задачи решены так:

**1 задача**:

```
int main(void) {
    int i, n, s, array[N];
    // ищем все подходящие числа
    int chisla[B + A];
    int chisla_col = 0;
    for (i = A; i <= B; i++) {
        s = 0;
        n = i;
        while (n > 0) {
            s += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        if (s < MAX) {
            chisla[chisla_col] = i;
            chisla_col++; //граница
        }
    }

    // ищем случайные числа из ранее найденных подходящих
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        n = rand() % chisla_col;
        array[i] = chisla[n];
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**2 задача**:

```
int main() {

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "w");
    int sum, sum1, sum2, i, array[N];
    double srednee1, srednee2;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = A + rand() % (B - A + 1);
        fprintf(file, "%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    fprintf(file, "***\n\n");

    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (N / 2); i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    sum1 = sum;
    srednee1 = sum1 / (N / 2);

    sum = 0;
    for (i = N / 2; i < N; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    sum2 = sum;
    srednee2 = sum2 / (N / 2);

    fclose(file);
    file = fopen("input.txt", "a");
    fprintf(file, "%d***%lf\n", sum1, srednee1);
    fprintf(file, "%d***%lf\n", sum2, srednee2);

    return 0;
}
```